# Is it possible to create your own drag and drop Mailchimp template?

Tags: drag-and-drop, mailchimp

I'd like to create a custom drag and drop template so I can increase the design possibilities without losing the functionality. I can't find anything in their documentation.

I was hoping to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhAd3.png), not sure if I'm missing something obvious but I can't find a drag and drop that allows for the different coloured background with columns too.

I could use a block of code but I can't edit the css styles so it wouldn't be responsive for mobile and also not very friendly for those who don't know html.

Answer (score 3):

Rather old question, but to who it might be helpfull:

If you code your own template and upload it to Mailchimp you lose the 'drag & drop' system/UX interface with the different blocks. You are able to create repeatable blocks but then it works with a dropdown list. This is (in my humble opinion) not that user friendly and takes a while before you fully understand how to use the dropdown. I had to explain it to a client earlier today and took a while before they understood it, so I decided to write them a manual for it.

But the design you want to create should be possible to make with a standard MC template. In the 'design' tab you will find settings to control background colors etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but while searching for this myself I stumbled upon a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620134/3041866).

Basically it is possible to code your own drag n' drop template, but the solution has not been documented.

1. Find one of the Mailchimp templates (either one of the basic templates or a custom template from the 'Themes' menu.
2. Use 'Inspect element' and copy the source code of the iFramed html-email.
3. Paste in your preferred HTML-editor and modify as intended
4. Create your own template from the 'Paste in code' mode
5. If you want custom modules to be added by default, edit using the menu 'Edit design' in the bottom of the screen.
6. Save and exit :)

Answer (score 0):

Still not possible, answer from the Mailchimp support: "At the moment, it's not currently possible to code a drag and drop template completely--one of our drag and drop template layouts will need to be selected, but you can drop in Code blocks to get a little more control over the styling of certain sections."

Though, if it's any help, it is possible to fully custom code your own template, and then add in mailchimps special Template language to the template to open up sections as editable within the campaign builder--or even duplicate certain sections of content. It's not quite the same as the drag drop templates, but adds similar functionality. More info on working with template language can be found here: https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-mailchimps-template-language/

Answer (score 0):

I found part of the answer on another topic: [[Is it possible to code drag&drop templates for mailchimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447364/is-it-possible-to-code-dragdrop-templates-for-mailchimp/58088578#58088578][1])

If you add the following code into your main content div or td it will enable the drag and drop block editor:

```
mc:container="body_container" mccontainer="body_container"
```

example:

```
<div  mc:container="body_container" mccontainer="body_container"></div>
```

This code will add a block editor region to the preheader section:

```
mc:container="preheader_container" mccontainer="preheader_container"
```

For the header:

```
mc:container="header_container" mccontainer="header_container"
```

For the footer:

```
mc:container="footer_container" mccontainer="footer_container"
```

Note: It doesn't seem to matter what you call the mc:container. Creating a new container with a different name worked. Although using just mc:container tag seems to work at first by itself, the mccontainer (no colon) tag is required for it to save properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own drag and drop template you need to add the following into your html coded template where you want the 'drag and drop' feature to exist.

```
<div id="templateBody" mc:container="container_name" mccontainer="container_name" class="tpl-container">                                
    <div mc:block="3502204" mc:blocktype="text" mcblock="3502204" mcblocktype="text" class="tpl-block"></div>
</div>
```

This can be repeated in your code multiple times for multiple insertions. I could not find documentation to indicate if the container name or block number needs to be unique, I did make it unique in my template.